# How to post status updates on myspace using asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone please tell how can I post status updates on myspace using asp.net C# ?

Thanks :D

Comment: Have you A written or tried anything. B realized that it is no longer 2006.

Comment: Yes I tried, and unfortunately the project we are working on must have the ability to update status on myspace :D

Answer (score 1):

Start here : http://developer.myspace.com/wordpress/

Comment: Thanks I already read the documentation, if someone could provide code sample that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this:

http://myspacetoolkit.codeplex.com/

The above site has an example of a connection

Also, the MySpace API documentation is quite good...  Look at this page for how to get and update a status.  It has a PHP sample, which should not be hard to translate to C#/Asp.Net:

http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Status_and_Mood_API